# TextColor property doesn't change it for leadingAssistiveLabel of MDCOutlinedTextField

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, mdc-components

According the Material Design docs (https://material.io/components/text-fields/ios#outlined-text-field) it is possible to change the color of leadingAssistiveLabel through textColor property ([docs screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dK6QO.png)).
I try to do this with orange color, but the color doesn't change.
[Code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1R0E2.png) and [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sF7yr.jpg).

How can I fix it?

Comment: may you show the code?

Comment: @Menaim, there are only 3 strings. Could you click, please, Code snippet link?

Answer (score 1):

Use this -
materialTF.setLeadingAssistiveLabelColor(.orange, for: .normal)